# Set only positive xticks on a horizontal barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis-labels

I would like to set positives values on the x axis on a horizontal barplot, but I don't know how to do.

A little example of my plot :
[image]

I would like to replace -500 and -1000 with 500 and 1000 on the left of 0.

And here my code, with y and y2 lists with values.

```
    y = [-i for i in y]
    plt.barh(range(1, len(y)+1), y, label="Serie_1")
    plt.barh(range(1, len(y2)+1), y2, alpha=0.5, color="r", label="Serie_2")
    plt.axvline(0, color="k")
    plt.yticks([i+1.5 for i in range(7)], range(7))
    plt.title("test")
    plt.legend()
```

I know that it's with xticks, but how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the label texts after the fact with their absolute values:

```
plt.gca().set_xticklabels([abs(x) for x in plt.gca().get_xticks()])
```

Comment: Oh thanks it works ! Such a long line for a little thing. Just note that it returns float values, and I just put a "int()" to remove decimals.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible solution: use [`plt.xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks). Here is a MWE.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = range(-5, 5)
y = range(-5, 5)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, [abs(i) for i in x])
plt.show()
```

which produces,

[image]